# Chrome wont open my PHP file hosted by XAMPP, even if I used HTTP (constantly loading)

Tags: php, xampp, wamp

I am using XAMPP to host a simple register script inside a folder called phptesting. But every time i try to view any possible errors in the script via chrome, it will never load. Its always loading. I used http://localhost/phptesting/register.php, and I've switched out the URL for so many others. When I look back at Apache, it switched ports, even if i didn't touch it. from 80 to some huge random number; "50947". I never set it to look like that.

To sum up, i put a PHP file in a folder. try to open it in google chrome (to see any errors chrome pulls up). And it will constantly load. I look back to XAMPP, the port has changed from 80 to some huge number. (WAMP does the same thing too, but I don't know if it changed the ports)

I appreciate all help, thanks
 [image: This is it switching ports when i try to access it.]

Comment: WAMP does the same thing too

Comment: @KurtVandenBranden C:/xampp/htdocs/

Comment: Is the link really `htpp://localhost/phptesting/register.php`? Or is it `http://localhost/phptesting/register.php`?

Comment: @LukeSavefrogs A small typo, thanks for pointing it out